# SQL query for finding Foreign key constraints

Tags: postgresql

I have one column , and i want to find in How many table that column used as foreign and also name of the table in which that column is used. I have PostgreSQL database . and i am using PG admin tool

```
select R.TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE u
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS FK
on U.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = FK.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
and U.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = FK.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
and U.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE R
 ON R.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = FK.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
 AND R.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = FK.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
 AND R.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME WHERE U.COLUMN_NAME='M_InLine_ID'
AND U.TABLE_NAME = 'M_InLine'
```

I tried above query but it snot given any output
Please help me out

Comment: select R.TABLE_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE u
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS FK
    on U.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = FK.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
    and U.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = FK.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    and U.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE R
    ON R.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = FK.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
    AND R.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = FK.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    AND R.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE U.COLUMN_NAME = 'M_InLine_ID'
  AND U.TABLE_NAME = 'M_InLine'

Comment: tried with above query

Comment: Please use English for your question. Do you whant to know which tables reference a certain column or which tables are referenced by a certain column?